# ejb value to a .jsp page

Tags: jsp, backing-beans

I have 2 xhtml forms that pass data in a backing bean.  I am trying to pass data from the first xhtml to a legacy jsp page and I just can not get it to work.  I have it working in the 2nd xhtml page so I just want it to do the same thing in the jsp.  Here are the 2 xhtml pages:

```
First Form:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
       <!-- Using a custom header -->
       <ui:include src="/resources/ADTHeader.xhtml" />
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="mypick"
            converter="#{categoryConverter}"
            value="#{gridMaster_backing.pickedGrid}" 
            title="TEST" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{gridMaster_backing.gridList}" var="prog" itemValue="#{prog.gridid}" itemLabel="#{prog.gridid} - #{prog.program} - #{prog.project} - #{prog.ci}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>



2nd Form:


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

      <h:head>
      </h:head>
 <h:body>
        <h1>Detailed Grid Data</h1>
        <h2>Grid Picked</h2>
        <p>#{gridMaster_backing.pickedGrid.longValue()}</p>
  <br></br>
<br></br>
<div class="data">
        <h:dataTable rendered="#{2 > 0}"
            value="#{gridMaster_backing.getGridmaster(gridMaster_backing.pickedGrid.longValue())}" var="cur"
            styleClass="data-table"
            columnClasses="data-cell,data-cell,data-cell,data-cell,data-cell"
            headerClass="data-cell header-cell">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                #{cur.gridid}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Program</f:facet>
                #{cur.program}
            </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-post this question with the session bean